# iOS : choose simulator device for screenshots

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, device

I want to publish an app to app store ,it ask me to take screenshots for 4 device :

iPhone : 6.5" Display.

iPhone : 5.5" Display.

iPad Pro (3rd Gen) : 12.9" Display.

iPad Pro (2nd Gen):12.9" Display.

which devices represent the above devices on XCode simulator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 6.5": iPhone XS Max / iPhone 11 Pro Max
- 5.5": iPhone 8 Plus / 7 Plus / 6s Plus / 6 Plus

If some device that you are looking for is not in your list, you can create that exact device in the Devices and Simulators window. In the menu bar, go to Window > Devices and Simulators (or press Command + Shift + 2), select the Simulators tab on the top left and then press the + button on the bottom left.